# Split TabItem cause style lost

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've a `TabControl` with this structure:

```
<TabControl>
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="20" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <local:Analysis />
</TabControl>
```

Now I need to split each `TabItem`, so I've create something like a `UserControl` with this structure:

```
<TabItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Header="Analysis" Style="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

the problem's that the `TabItem` imported with namespace `local:` doesn't take the style of the `TabControl` in the `Resource`. 
So for solve this  I need to put the style resource in each `TabItem`, this will cause redundancy code.

How can I take the style of `TabControl Resource` in the splitted `TabItem`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own style as a static resource in your App.xaml or your Window.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="MyTabItemStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="20" />
    </Style>  
</Application.Resources>
```

You give your style a name (`MyTabItemStyle` in this example) which is based on the `MetroTabItem` style.

Then, instead of using the `MetroTabItem` style directly in your custom `TabItem`, you use your own style `MyTabItemStyle` like this:

```
<TabItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
     mc:Ignorable="d" Header="Analysis" Style="{StaticResource MyTabItemStyle}">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```